# How can I use map service ( published on Arcgis Server 10.4.1) from another computer?

Tags: arcgis-server

With ArcGIS Server 10.2, the map service url is in a format like http://{ip}+ port/arcgis/rest/services/yourservice, in Arcgis Server 10.4.1, the map service url replace the ip with local domain, for now I can only load the service on my local machine using Arcgis Javascript. How can I make the map service public to all the local network users, like a different computer on the same network?

[image]

Comment: What happens when you specify the url as in 10.2 - `http://{ip}+ port/arcgis/rest/services/yourservice`?

Comment: A message saying "Invalid redirect_uri Error: 400" and the page was redirect to a url started with the domain name.